# Using Offline Indexing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, winforms, indexing

I've written a .Net application which has an SQL Server 2008 R2 database with relatively small number of tables, but in some tables there might be some 100,000,000 records! For improving performance of SELECTs, I've created necessary indexes and it works well. But, as everyone knows, indexes need to be rebuilt when they are fragmented.

We have installed an SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on one of customer PCs plus my Winforms application. Three more PCs connect to this database over regular LAN, and everything seems fine.

Now, the problem is that, I want to rebuild indexes, for example every time a user starts using my program on ANY of the machines. Well, I can execute several ALTER INDEXes, but as stated in MS docs, OFFLINE indexing will lock the tables for period of indexing. Which means other users will lose access to tables when a user starts the program! I know there is an ONLINE option, but it doesn't work in Express edition of SQL Server.

In other environments with a real server running all the time, I would create an Agent Job which rebuilt indexes over night.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a normal 24/7 server running, it's difficult to do such maintenance automatically without disturbing users. I don't think putting that job at the application startup is a good idea, as it can really start many times together without a real reason, and also slows down startup significantly if tables are big, in addition to keep everyone else out as you say.

I would opt for 2 choices:

- Setup a job on the "server" to do the rebuild on either SQL Server startup or computer startup. It will slow down the initialization of that PC when the user first power it on, but once done, it should work OK, and most likely with similar results to the nightly job.
- Add an option in the application to launch the reindexing job manually when the user wants to do it, warning that it will take some time and during the process anyone else cannot use it. While this provides maximum flexibility, it relies on the user doing so when they start noting delays.

Comment: As the users of my application have no idea about indexing whatsoever, I would go for the first option. How can I schedule a job on computer startup? I checked schedule options in SQL Server and I saw 'Start automatically when Agent starts'.

Comment: That's the right option, it runs when the agent starts, that should be right after the main SQL Server service starts, that should be after Windows boot if the service is put on automatic. No matter what, as long as the agent runs, when the system becomes available, it will run the task.